# PHP - Search in specific array value

Tags: arrays, loops, if-statement

I want to Search in Array value by in_array Function and For loop. My code:

```
$input = "a";
$arrays = array("cdf","abs","tgf");

$counter = count($arrays);

for ($i=0; $i<$counter; $i++){

    if(in_array($input,$arrays) !== true){
        echo "Found <br>";
    } else {
        echo "Not Found";
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Not Found
Found
Not Found
```

But, `if(in_array($input,$arrays[$i]) !== true)` not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `in_array("a", "cdf")`, which is what `in_array($input, $arrays[$i])` could become, isn't working is because `"cdf"` isn't an array.

Are you trying to find array elements in `$arrays` that contain the letter `a`?
In that case you should search array elements with `strpos()` to determine if a string contains another string. You can also use `foreach` instead of `for` if iterating over the array is all you want to do.

```
$input = "a";
$arrays = array("cdf","abs","tgf");

foreach ($arrays as $key => $value)
{
    if (strpos($value, $input) !== false)
        echo "Found in $key<br>";
    else
        echo "Not Found<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, You say "cdf" isn't an array. You mean in_array only worked for all array() value and can't use for specific value ?

Comment: Read the manual for `in_array()`, it checks if a specific element is in an array, not part of a string which is in an array.